# How to save a card in nativescript using stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, nativescript

Someone knows how to save the cards and then pay with them, so that the user does not have to enter their card details every time

Comment: The Stripe docs are quite good and the syntax of nativescript is very similar to the languages they show. Are you having a specific error? Please post code and a stack trace :) https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Answer (score 0):

While there is no official Stripe support for NativeScript, it looks like you can just write JavaScript.

In which case you'd want to follow this guide to save a PaymentMethod and charge it later: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that build upon the Stripe APIs and SDKs available but there is no quick easy answer for the question you're asking as far as I'm aware.

After googling, I was able to find some nativescript wrapper libraries which might be a good starting point:

https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-stripe - supports both Android and iOS
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-stripe-sdk - builds upon the library linked above but only supports iOS

In response to your question regarding saving cards for future payment use, you would use the Stripe provided APIs to handle that by creating a customer object within the Stripe system and then adding payment sources for that customer from your UI.

Once you needed to make a payment request, you would reference the customer's selected payment method (might require showing additional UI in your app that you create to in order to allow for selection) in your payment intent.

I would recommend reading up on the Stripe documentation to understand this flow: https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart